# Infinite Loop in my MIPS asm code due to $ra having incorrect address

Tags: assembly, mips

I have two methods, print_board and print_line.

print_board calls print_line multiple times to print each row of our game board, sending it the index of where we want to start printing in $a1, when we've printed all of our rows, print_board will finish by printing the bottom border of our board.

For some reason, when we've finished printing all of our rows it will just start printing the bottom border infinite times.

It appears that I've made a mistake in managing my stacks and return addresses between methods, but I can't find where the error is. Everything looks ok to me! Perhaps another pair of eyes can help.

```
print_board:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $ra, 12($sp)
    sw      $s2, 8($sp)
    sw      $s1, 4($sp)
    sw      $s0, 0($sp)

    # Initialize registers
    la      $s0, board
    move    $s1, $zero
    move    $s2, $zero

    # Print top of the board
    la      $a0, h_sep
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Print Row 1
    li      $a1, 0
    jal     print_line

    # Print Row 2
    li      $a1, 6
    jal     print_line

    # Print Separator
    la      $a0, h_sep
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    #... Print rest of rows

    # Print Bottom Border
    la      $a0, h_sep    # --> Lets call this line 100
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    lw      $ra, 12($sp)
    lw      $s2, 8($sp)
    lw      $s1, 4($sp)
    lw      $s0, 0($sp)
    jr      $ra          #-> At this point $ra has the memory 
                         # location of Line 100, so it just repeatedly
                         # runs that part of code.


print_line:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $ra, 12($sp)
    sw      $s2, 8($sp)
    sw      $s1, 4($sp)
    sw      $s0, 0($sp)

    add     $s0, $s0, $a1

    # Print left border
    la      $a0, v_sep
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Print cell 1
    lb      $a0, ($s0)
    li      $v0, 1
    syscall

    # Print Space
    la      $a0, space
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Move to the next cell
    addi    $s0, $s0, 1

    # Print new line \n
    la      $a0, new_line
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall

    ... Print rest of cells

    # Destroy the stack
    lw      $ra, 12($sp)
    lw      $s2, 8($sp)
    lw      $s1, 4($sp)
    lw      $s0, 0($sp)
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: I don't speak mips (at all).  But since no one else has responded, I'll take a shot.  I see where you adjust the stack to make room for the new values (`addi    $sp, $sp, -16`), but I don't see you put it back.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd You were absolutely correct, I was missing the ( addi $sp, $sp, 16). If you would like to suggest the same as an answer, I can give ya some rep for it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not familiar with MIPS assembly, it appears that while you create room on the stack (`addi $sp, $sp, -16`), you don't release it when you are done.  Presumably something like `addi $sp, $sp, 16`.